# Replacing Rows in a large data frame in R

Tags: r

I have to manually collect some rows so based on the R Cookbook, it recommended me to pre-allocate some memory for a large data frame. Say my code is

```
dataSize <- 500000;
shoesRead <- read.csv(file="someShoeCsv.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",");

shoes <- data.frame(size=integer(dataSize), price=double(dataSize),
         cost=double(dataSize), retail=double(dataSize));
```

So now, I have some data about shoes which I imported via csv, and then I perform some calculation and want to insert into the data frame `shoes`. Let's say the `someShoeCsv.csv` has a column called `ukSize` and so

```
usSize <- ukSize * 1.05 #for example
```

My question is how do I do so? Running the code, noting now I have a `usSize` variable which was transformed from the `ukSize` column, read from the csv file:

```
shoes <- rbind(shoes, 
               data.frame("size"=usSize, "price"=price, 
                          "cost"=cost, "retail"=retail));
```

adds to the already large data frame.

I have experimented with doing the `list` and then `rbind` but understand that it is tedious and so I am thinking of using this method but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to replace some of the pre-allocated rows with new data, you could do so like this:

```
Nreplace = length(usSize)
shoes$size[1:Nreplace] <- usSize
shoes$price[1:Nreplace] <- shoesRead$price
```

And so on, for the rest of the columns.

Here's some unsolicited advice. Looking at the code you've included, you reference `ukSize` and `price` etc without referencing the data frame, which makes it appear like you've done `attach(shoesRead)`. Definitely **never** use `attach()`. If you want the price vector, for example, just do `shoesRead$price`. It's just a little bit more typing for the sake of much more readable code.